# Get a certain line (ie. first) of a contenteditable div and replace it

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

With textarea it is quite straightforward:

```
<textarea id='elememt'>
  1. Blah blah blah.
  <div>2. Header</div>
  3
</textarea>

var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');

alert(lines[0]; // show the first line "1. Blah blah blah."
alert(lines[2]; // show the third line "3"
```

But how do I do the same with a contenteditable DIV?

I've looked at this:

```
var first_line = $("#element")
                       .contents()
                       .filter(function() { 
                           return !!$.trim( this.innerHTML || this.data ); 
                       })
                       .first();
```

Which gets the first line but how do I get the third line and so on?

Comment: Unfortunately all browsers have different behavior with new lines in contenteditable elements... E.g, FF will just append a `<br>` element, while chrome will wrap your lines in `<div>` elements, and I guess other UAs uses other tricks which would make it hard for us to know what the actual content is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.html()`, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/.*\n/g` to match one or more characters including newline character, `String.prototype.replace()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.join()` to return original matches, replacing string or part of string at selected index of matched lines.

Given `html` at Question, the first element within the array returned by `.match()` will be a newline character; use `3` to match fourth element of returned array.

```js
$().ready(function() {
  var element = $("#element");
  var matches = element.html().match(/.*\n/g);
  console.log(matches);
  var third_line = matches[3];
  var replacement = "4";
  element.html(function(i, html) {
    return matches.map(function(_html, index) {
     return index != 3 ? _html : _html.replace(/3/, replacement)
   }).join("")
  });
  console.log(element.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<div id='element'>
  1. Blah blah blah.
  <div>2. Header</div>
  3
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but what happens if my DIV content doesn't have HTML elements?  It returns a blank.

Comment: Also, how do I replace the third line?

Comment: If `div` does not contain `html` elements would probably throw an error at `[0].textContent`. You can first check `.length` of jQuery object returned by `.filter()` then determine if any indexes can be selected, and to which maximum index. `if (third_line.length) {var max = third_line.length; if (2 <= max) {third_line.eq(2)[0].textContent = //new text content here; or third_line.eq(2)[0].innerHTML = // new html here}}`

Comment: This would work only if the div element doesn't have other non-block elements : `<div id="edit" contenteditable><b>e</b>d<i>i</i>t me
</div>` would make it fail.

Comment: @Kaiido Did not check if the pattern using `.contents()` and `.filter()` returned expected result. _"But how do I do the same with a contenteditable DIV?"_ ,  _"Which gets the first line but how do I get the third line and so on?"_ , _"If `.contents()`, `.filter()` approach returns expected results"_. No `html` having `contenteditable` attribute appears at original Question.

Comment: @Kaiido What is the critical flaw? How can Answer be improved given `html` and `javascript` at Question? What is your suggestion? Did not describe approach as being correct as to `.contents()`, `.filter()`. Answers can be edited, where OP and user which  answers Question exchange communication, and the requirement becomes clearer. Have you considered posting an Answer?

Comment: TLDR : even if it does fix OP's particular issue, try to make it as general as possible.

Comment: @guest271314, As I've said, I can do this with a textarea element, but had no idea how to do it using contenteditable DIV, which is why I'm asking.  Instead of asking lazily, I tried to seek a solution before coming here, which is what you see in the original post.  I understand the first solution which shows me the 3rd line, but it doesn't replace it which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What I'm doing now is reading the text inside a DIV element into an array using  the code above, getting the text at a line number, replacing that with another text and output that array back into DIV.

Comment: @Kaiido, I understood the first solution but didn't understand the second part, which was to replace the text in a DIV.

Comment: Okay I found a more suitable solution which I will update soon.